# EF Core multiple navigation properties produce circular dependency

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have the following mapping configuration:

Entry-Class:

```cs
entity
    .HasOne(e => e.CurrentHandling)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Entry>(e => e.CurrentHandlingID)
    ;

entity
    .HasMany(e => e.Handlings)
    .WithOne(h => h.Entry)
    .HasForeignKey(h => h.EntryID)
    ;
```

Handling-Class:

```cs
entity
    .HasOne(h => h.Entry)
    .WithMany(e => e.Handlings)
    .HasForeignKey(h => h.EntryID)
        .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

ERM:
[image]

When I try to save the context I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected in the data to be saved: 'ForeignKey: Entry.CurrentHandlingID -> Handling.HandlingID Unique ToPrincipal: CurrentHandling, ForeignKey: Handling.EntryID -> Entry.EntryID ToDependent: Handlings ToPrincipal: Entry'.'

Test-Data:

```cs
errorRepo.EnableBulkModus();

var handling = errorRepo.AddHandling(new Handling {
     CorrectedMessage = "correct",
     HandlingStatusID = 7,
     Updated = DateTime.UtcNow,
     UpdatedBy = nameof(DbInitializer)
});

var reference = errorRepo.AddReference(new Reference {
    ForeignKeyTypeID = 4,
    ForeignKeyValue = "42",
    Name = "SystemB",
    ReferenceTypeID = 6
});

var entry = errorRepo.AddEntry(new Entry {
    CurrentHandling = handling,
    DisplayMessage = "Wrong!",
    ErrorMessage = "error!",
    Inserted = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-5),
    OriginalMessage = "incorrect",
    InsertedBy = nameof(DbInitializer),
    UUID = Guid.NewGuid(),
    Reference = reference,
    StatusID = 5
});

handling.Entry = entry;
entry.Handlings.Add(handling);

errorRepo.DisableBulkModus(true);
```

`errorRepo.EnableBulkModus();` sets just a flag which indicates the repository not to save when calling `CommitChanges()`
Same with `errorRepo.DisableBulkModus(true);`, it sets the flag to false. The boolean indicated, that the repository should perform a `CommitChanges()`.

How do I have to change my mapping to avoid a circular dependency?

kind Regards.

**EDIT (11.03.2017)**

I removed the mapping from the Handling-Class and added the line `.OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Restrict)` in the Entry-Class:

```cs
    entity
        .HasMany(e => e.Handlings)
        .WithOne(h => h.Entry)
        .HasForeignKey(h => h.EntryID)
        .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
        ;
```

Same exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected in the data to be saved: 'ForeignKey: Entry.CurrentHandlingID -> Handling.HandlingID Unique ToPrincipal: CurrentHandling, ForeignKey: Handling.EntryID -> Entry.EntryID ToDependent: Handlings ToPrincipal: Entry'.'

Comment: See EDIT (11.03.2017).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See this:

```cs
// 1.
var entry = errorRepo.AddEntry(new Entry {
    CurrentHandling = handling,
    ...
});
...
// 2.
handling.Entry = entry;
```

The code below 1. requires `entry` to receive `handling`'s primary key as foreign key. The code below 2. requires `handling` to reveive `entry`'s primary key as FK: a chicken-and-egg problem.

Since `handling` depends on `entry` (because of the 1-0..1 relationship), `entry` should be inserted first --not having its `CurrentHandling` property set yet. Then save changes, so `entry` knows its generated PK. Then set `entry.CurrentHandling` and `handling.Entry` and save changes again.

You may want to wrap this code in a transaction.

By the way, the line `entry.Handlings.Add(handling);` is redundant.

Comment: Thank you very much. The order of the inserts solved the problem. Additionally I had to allow NULL for the CurrentHandling Column.