# Child Table Properties are not fetching in ef core inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

i have following entities..

```
    public class Paper
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string PaperCode { get; set; }
        ...
    }
    public class MCQPaper : Paper
    {
        public ICollection<MCQQuestion> Questions { get; set; }
    }
    public class MCQQuestion : Question
    {
        public int MCQPaperId { get; set; }
        public MCQPaper MCQPaper { get; set; }

        public int? MCQOptionId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("MCQOptionId")]
        public MCQOption TrueAnswer { get; set; }
        public ICollection<MCQOption> MCQOptions { get; set; }
    }
    public class MCQOption
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string OptionText { get; set; }
    }
```

and i am trying to fetch MCQPaper based on unique papercode but it always gives me empty collection of Questions

here is my Query inside Repository..

```
        public MCQPaper GetByPaperCode(string paperCode)
        {
            var ans = AppDbContext.MCQPapers
                .Where(paper => paper.PaperCode.Equals(paperCode))
                //.Include(paper => paper.Questions)
                //    .ThenInclude(que => que.MCQOptions)
                .Include(paper => paper.Questions)
                    .ThenInclude(que => que.MCQPaper)
                //.Include(paper => paper.Questions)
                //    .ThenInclude(que => que.TrueAnswer)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            return ans;
        }
```

here i have tried various combinations of include() and theninclude() but none of them work for me

and lastly ignore grammer mistakes if any

thankyou in advance

Comment: are you tried to put where after the include ? remove where and put your condition to FirstOrDefaut()

.FirstOrDefault(paper => paper.PaperCode.Equals(paperCode));

Comment: thank you for suggestion i will try it and let you know

Comment: @puko still it is not working

Comment: are you sure that you have some questions inserted in database ? with right foreign key ?

Comment: Check this article
https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/foreignkey-attribute

Comment: one table per heirachy? or one table per type? Should MCQOption have a MCQQuestionId for the FK? Since there's 2 FK's between these tables, do you need to define both the FK's explicitly?

Comment: @jeremy I have used one table per heirachy or discriminator column approach

Comment: @puko I have inserted data in database using two different queries in one transaction as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719796/ef-core-multiple-navigation-properties-produce-circular-dependency)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after going threw comments and searching on google i have found solution

using two queries this problem can be solved because here i have circular dependency between `MCQQuestion`  and `MCQOption`

so solution is ....

```
        public MCQPaper GetByPaperCode(string paperCode)
        {
            using var transaction = AppDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction();
            MCQPaper ans = new MCQPaper();
            try
            {
                ans = AppDbContext.MCQPapers
                .FirstOrDefault(paper => paper.PaperCode.Equals(paperCode));
                var questions = AppDbContext.MCQQuestions
                    .Include(que => que.MCQOptions)
                    .Where(que => que.MCQPaperId == ans.Id);
                ans.Questions = questions.ToList();
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
            return ans;
        }
```