# ef core - two different relationships for the same tables

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-relationship, ef-core-5.0

I have two tables which have two different relationships:

```
class Suggestion {
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    Guid LastRevisionId { get; set; }
    SuggestionRevision LastRevision { get; set; }

    ICollection<SuggestionRevision> SuggestionRevisions { get; set; }
}

class SuggestionRevision {
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    Guid SuggestionId { get; set; }
    Suggestion Suggestion { get; set; }
}
```

I can have many suggestion revisions for a suggestion. This is one-to-many relationship.

Additionally, I keep another column `LastRevision` for easy access to the last revision of the suggestion in Entity Framework using `Include()`, and this is a one-to-one relationship (at least I would like it to be).

I have `OnModelCreating` as below:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Suggestion>()
        .HasMany(b => b.SuggestionRevisions)
        .WithOne(w => w.Suggestion);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Suggestion>()
        .HasOne(b => b.LastRevision)
        .WithOne()
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
}
```

However, this did not work.
How should I configure this?

Also, keeping the last revision id is a logical design choice? Seems I am missing something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer in this post: [Multiple relations between entities in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66865640/multiple-relations-between-entities-in-ef-core/66866141#66866141) and my model configuration is as below:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<SuggestionRevision>()
        .HasOne(b => b.Suggestion)
        .WithMany(w => w.SuggestionRevisions)
        .HasForeignKey(w => w.SuggestionId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Suggestion>()
        .HasOne(b => b.LastRevision)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey<Suggestion>(w => w.LastRevisionId);
}
```

I guess the key point is determining the primary and reference tables.